# Automapper ProjectTo map DateTimeOffSet Truncate millisecond to return Odata

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, odata, automapper, datetimeoffset

I'm developing a small project use postgresql, automapper, and odata.

I have entity:

```
public class LanguageReadModel : Entity<Guid>
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enable { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public Guid? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ModifiedTime { get; set; }
    public Guid? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public Guid? DeletedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DeletedTime { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TranslateReadModel> Translates { get; set; }
}
```

and dto:

```
public class LanguageDto : Entity<Guid>
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Enable { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public Guid? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ModifiedTime { get; set; }
    public Guid? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public Guid? DeletedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DeletedTime { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TranslateDto> Translates { get; set; }
}
```

LanguageProfile:

```
public class LanguageProfile : Profile
{
    public LanguageProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<LanguageReadModel, LanguageDto>();
    }
}
```

ProjectTo:

```
public Task<IQueryable<LanguageDto>> Handle(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
      var result = _languageRepository.Queryable().ProjectTo<LanguageDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
      return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

And this code return DateTimeOffSet format is: "2021-08-12T17:25:14.359611Z"
I want return: "2021-08-12T17:25:14.xxZ"

I have tried 2 way:

1.

Truncate method:

```
public static DateTimeOffset Truncate(this DateTimeOffset dateTime, TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
            if (timeSpan == TimeSpan.Zero) return dateTime; // Or could throw an ArgumentException
            if (dateTime == DateTime.MinValue || dateTime == DateTime.MaxValue) return dateTime; // do not modify "guard" values
            return dateTime.AddTicks(-(dateTime.Ticks % timeSpan.Ticks));
 }
```

and Profile:

```
CreateMap<LanguageReadModel, LanguageDto>().ConvertUsing((source, destination) =>
{
      destination.CreatedTime = source.CreatedTime.Truncate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
      destination.ModifiedTime = source.ModifiedTime.Truncate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
      destination.DeletedTime = source.DeletedTime.Truncate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
      return destination;
})
```

or

```
public LanguageProfile()
{
            CreateMap<LanguageAggregateRoot, LanguageDto>();
            CreateMap<LanguageInitializedEvent, LanguageReadModel>();
            CreateMap<LanguageReadModel, LanguageDto>().ForMember(dest => dest.CreatedTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CreatedTime.Truncate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ModifiedTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ModifiedTime.Truncate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DeletedTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DeletedTime.Truncate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))));
}
```

But when user send OrderBy this way cann't translate Truncate method. `The LINQ expression 'DbSet<LanguageReadModel>()\n    .OrderBy(l => l.CreatedTime\n        .Truncate(00:00:01))' could not be translated`

2. I use UseAsDataSource and OnEnumerated to map properties as:

```
    {
        var result = _languageRepository.Queryable().UseAsDataSource(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).For<LanguageDto>().OnEnumerated((dtos) =>
        {
            var languages = dtos.Cast<LanguageDto>();
            foreach (var dto in languages)
            {
                dto.CreatedTime = dto.CreatedTime.Truncate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                dto.ModifiedTime = dto.ModifiedTime.Truncate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                dto.DeletedTime = dto.DeletedTime.Truncate(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }
        });
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
```

This working with orderBy but not working with expand query.

What can i do that?

Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData (8.0.1)

AutoMapper: (10.1.1)

AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping: (4.1.1)

Thanks for your support.

Comment: The real question here is how would you do it without AM. It should be easy then to port that to AM.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I use DateTimeOffSet.UtcNow when insert/update. I fancy "2021-08-12T17:25:14.359611Z" = 05:25:14 PM or "2021-08-12T09:53:23.359611Z" = 09:53:23 AM?